# jQuery Target classes separately

Tags: jquery, html

**I have a HTML code like this.**

```
<!-- Every time string is different -->
<span class="time_string">123456789</span> 
<span class="time_string">981251100</span>
<span class="time_string">051036626</span>
<span class="time_string">016165656</span>
```

**I want Jquery change the time string to date**

```
<!-- Look every date is different -->
<span class="time_string">25 March 2017</span> 
<span class="time_string">28 April 2017</span>
<span class="time_string">14 January 2017</span>
<span class="time_string">21 December 2015</span>
```

**To do this I have used this Jquery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function timestr_to_date(time_string){
        // this function will convert the time string to date
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // getting the time string
        var time_string = $('.time_string').html();

        // converting the time string to date by using function
        var date = timestr_to_date(time_string);

        // replacing the time_string to date
        $('.time_string').html(date);

    });

</script>
```

**But it I got every date same**

```
<!-- PROBLEM: Every date are same -->
<span class="time_string">25 March 2017</span> 
<span class="time_string">25 March 2017</span>
<span class="time_string">25 March 2017</span>
<span class="time_string">25 March 2017</span>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Because There is no limits on <span> and I don't know how much <span> would I have. I will use PHP to generate those. And there will be no fixed number

Comment: There's no need for ids here at all. Classes are prefect for this as it does not limit the number of elements, or require any future maintenance

Comment: @JaTurna ah I see that's fair enough then :) will remove my comment :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix this you need to loop through each `.time_string` element and amend their values individually.

To do that you could use an `each()` loop, or more succinctly, by providing a function to `text()` which takes the current value and returns the value you want to update to. Try this:

```js
$('.time_string').text(function(i, t) {
  return timestr_to_date(t);
});

function timestr_to_date(time_string) {
  // your date formatting logic here, this is just for this example:
  return new Date(time_string * 1000);
}
```

```css
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="time_string">123456789</span>
<span class="time_string">981251100</span>
<span class="time_string">051036626</span>
<span class="time_string">016165656</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `jQuery.each` https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$('.time_string').each(function() {
  var time_string = $(this).html();

  var date = timestr_to_date(time_string);

  $(this).html(date);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should loop through all the classes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   // getting the time string
    $('.time_string').each(function(){
         var time_string = $(this).text();

      // converting the time string to date by using function
      var date = timestr_to_date(time_string);

      // replacing the time_string to date
       $(this).text(date);
       });

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through all `span` with class `time_string` and change their value please find below snippet for more info

```js
function timestr_to_date(time_string) {
  // this function will convert the time string to date
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".time_string").each(function() {
    // getting the time string
    var time_string = $(this).html();
    // converting the time string to date by using function
    var date = timestr_to_date(time_string);
    // replacing the time_string to date
    $(this).html(date);
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="time_string">123456789</span> 
<span class="time_string">981251100</span>
<span class="time_string">051036626</span>
<span class="time_string">016165656</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make loop in all span tags, try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "span" ).each(function() {

        // getting the time string
        var time_string = $(this).html();

        // converting the time string to date by using function
        var date = timestr_to_date(time_string);

        // replacing the time_string to date
        $(this).html(date);

   });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have to iterate all span tags and convert the timestamp into the date Like Below

```
$('span.time_string').each(function(){
     var time = $(this).text();      
     var date = timestr_to_date(time);
     $(this).text(date);
});
```